# Why onDrag method runs millions of times?

Tags: android

I try to implement a little **drag and drop system in my project**, so far i have:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDrag(View eventView, DragEvent event) {

    final int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action) {

    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

        DragAndDropState.itWasDropped = false;

        draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();

        if (draggedView.getParent() != null) {


            draggedTargetParent = (View) draggedView.getParent();
            DragAndDropState.dragStartPosition = (Integer) draggedTargetParent.getTag();

            Log.i("START draggedView ", draggedView.toString());
            Log.i("START parent: ", draggedTargetParent.toString());

        }



        ((ViewGroup) eventView).removeView((View) event.getLocalState());

        return true;


    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: //............... more code
```

And i see in logcat after i longclicked a view:

```
09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START draggedView(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.ItemInSlotView@42ae2ef0
    09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START parent:(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.Slot@42ab7e68
    09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START draggedView(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.ItemInSlotView@42ae2ef0
    09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START parent:(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.Slot@42ab7e68
    09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START draggedView(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.ItemInSlotView@42ae2ef0
    09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START parent:(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.Slot@42ab7e68
    09-03 14:08:48.236: I/START draggedView(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.ItemInSlotView@42ae2ef0
    09-03 14:08:48.246: I/START parent:(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.Slot@42ab7e68
    09-03 14:08:48.246: I/START draggedView(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.ItemInSlotView@42ae2ef0
    09-03 14:08:48.246: I/START parent:(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.Slot@42ab7e68
    09-03 14:08:48.246: I/START draggedView(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.ItemInSlotView@42ae2ef0
    09-03 14:08:48.246: I/START parent:(12796): hu.fun.views.slot.Slot@42ab7e68
    09-03 14:08:49.137: I/ViewRootImpl(12796): Reporting drop result: true
```

That is right. **I got 6 (six!)** onDragEvents triggered **by one longclick** with **one onLongClick listenr** on **one View targeted**.

Could anyobdy explain my why is it happening, or why is it good?

I really would like to work with only one of these things, it is pure annyoying to flood the logcat with messages likes this i cannot debug a way like this.

Comment: where is the break statement in your code.it should be present before the action_drop.

Comment: @hamad You don't need a break if you have a return.

Comment: provide some more code so that we can understand it well..!!!